# How to convert DATE and TIMESTAMP string types to DATE types in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a temp table where the input date and input timestamps are always of type `string`. I want to see if there is 1 single function to which handles these both types and gives me a `DATE` in the output in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Here is my code -

```
with temp as 
(
select "1" as id
,  "20170801" as input_date_string -- this is of string type
,  "2017-08-01 15:30:00" as input_timestamp_string -- this is also of string type
)

select id
, input_date_string
, input_timestamp_string
, FORMAT_DATE( '%Y-%m-%d' ,  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', input_date_string) ) AS output_format_date
from temp
```

I am able to format the `input_date_string`. But I want to be able to handle both the types - `date` and `timestamp` string. Is there 1 single function that will give me `2017-08-01` in the output?

To reiterate, the input can be either `"20170801"` or `"2017-08-01 15:30:00"` and my function should return me `2017-08-01`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below option for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION CUSTOM_FORMAT_DATE(str STRING) AS (
  CASE 
    WHEN LENGTH(str) = 8 THEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', str))
    ELSE FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', DATE(TIMESTAMP(str)))
  END
);
WITH temp AS 
(
SELECT "1" AS id
,  "20170801" AS input_date_string -- this is of string type
,  "2017-08-01 15:30:00" AS input_timestamp_string -- this is also of string type
)

SELECT id
, input_date_string
, input_timestamp_string
, CUSTOM_FORMAT_DATE(input_date_string)
, CUSTOM_FORMAT_DATE(input_timestamp_string)
FROM temp
```

with output

```
Row id  input_date_string   input_timestamp_string  f0_         f1_  
1   1   20170801            2017-08-01 15:30:00     2017-08-01  2017-08-01
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `SAFE.` prefix and `COALESCE()` to do that:

```
with temp as 
(
select "1" as id, "20170801" as input_date_string 
union all
select "2", "2017-08-01 15:30:00"
)

select id
, COALESCE(
  FORMAT_DATE( '%Y-%m-%d' ,  SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', input_date_string) ),
  FORMAT_DATETIME( '%Y-%m-%d' ,  SAFE.PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', input_date_string) )
  ) result_date
from temp
```

Output:

```
+----+------------+
| id |result_date |
+----+------------+
| 1  | 2017-08-01 |
| 2  | 2017-08-01 |
+----+------------+
```